# ctrl+break не работает в dosbox

Tags: c++

ctrl+break не работает в dosbox

программирую в turbo c++ в dosbox, не могу завершить срочно программу во время выполнения, dosbox не принимает ctrl+break. в keymapper dosbox не знаю как сделать чтобы принимал. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.